# certificatesforexchange.com, has anyone used them?

Tags: exchange-2007, unified-communications

I need to purchase a SAN cert for my Exchange 2007 box and it needs 6 domain names in the list. I've been looking at different companies, such as Entrust and Digicert, which are a couple of the companies mentioned in this [MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=929395) article. However, i've just found [this site](https://certificatesforexchange.com/), where I can get a 10-domain SAN cert for $109/yr. Thats almost a quarter of the cost of those other guys for the same cert. Does anyone here have any experience with them? It almost seems to good to be true.

On another note, is one SSL provider really any better than the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I bought one of their SAN certs, and it all worked out perfectly. It's being used to secure an Exchange 2007 and MOSS 2007 server at the same time. So far WinMo and iPhone are cool with the cert, and no browser issues, which is to be expected. Install was painless as well. Even after the private key was lost on my first try (I think that was my fault), it was painless to re-key the cert with a fresh CSR and re download it. So far, I would definitely recommend to a friend. Best of all, $109 got me a 10 domain cert for a year!

Answer (score 1):

If you look a bit deeper, you'll see that this service comes from GoDaddy. We've been using their certs for many other purposes, no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've used them before for single certs for Exchange and they have been fine, no experience with SAN certs i'm afraid though. I believe they use Starfield as they're issuing authority, which was trusted by everything I needed, including Windows Mobile Devices (and iPhones).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Windows Mobile 5 doesn't have the roots for these certs.

Comment: As far as I know they do, but the correct intermediate certificates need to be on the exchange/isa server... I have step-by-step instructions from support on how to set this up so even Mobile 5.0 devices will be happy