# exchange 2010 certificate confusion!

Tags: ssl, exchange-2010

I'm new to Exchange and I'm having trouble configuring the certificates.

At the moment I have a ssl certificate for one domain (mail.mydomain.com).  Do I need a seperate certificate for local domains (domain.local) for local client access?

I'm also getting errors for autodiscover.mydomain.com but I guess that's because we need a wildcard certificate or something.

Help, I'm really confused!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a UC cert. They are designed for exchange.
e.g. Digicert sells these.
http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/95713/exchange-certificates-dont-match-up/96656#96656) regarding UC certificates.